# Issue creating Jar files (repository is from github)

Tags: java

Creating a Jar file:

I want to create Jar files from a Github Java repository. How can I create below Jar files?

Jars to create:

`geo-ip-java.jar`

`hive-udf-geo-ip-jtg.jar`

Git URL: https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive-geoip

I found we can create them as below syntax, but seems it is using maven to compile them:

```
jar cf jar_file.jar file.java
```

Comment: Execute `mvn package`? https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_create_a_JAR_and_install_it_in_my_local_repository

Comment: @Robert, I ran mvn package but I am getting below error: [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal on project hive-geoip: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.m6d:hive-geoip:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.jointhegrid:hive_test:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

As this is a maven project (as seen that the file `pom.xml` exists) you can create the target artifact (in your case the `jar` file) by simply executing `mvn package`.

If you want to use the `jar` file in another maven project (as dependency) then it is more usefull to use `mvn install` as this also installs the artifact in your local repository.

Comment: Hi, do I run command "mvn package" inside hive-geoip directory where there is pom.xml file? When I do that, I get this error message "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hive-geoip: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.m6d:hive-geoip:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.jointhegrid:hive_test:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]"

Comment: @Riomario then you need also to download this artiact (ask the author of the library where to get it).

Comment: When I run mvn install on the git directory, I get below error: [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal on project hive-geoip: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.m6d:hive-geoip:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.jointhegrid:hive_test:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]